# Is it possible to create an XmlReader from output SqlParameter of type SqlDbType.Xml?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, xml-serialization, sqlparameter

This is my parameter definition:

```
var param = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "@param",
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Xml,
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
    Size = int.MaxValue
};
command.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Then I do:

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And finally:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
return serializer.Deserialize(
    new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(param.Value.ToString())))
    as MyClass;
```

Do I really need to convert to string and then byte array?

Comment: You can't just `select` it and use `ExecuteXmlReader`?

Comment: @Marc: SQL code is somewhat out of my control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Parameter.SqlValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.sqlvalue.aspx), will return a `SqlXml` instance and you can use [`CreateReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlxml.createreader.aspx) to get an XML reader. Then use the [`XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz8csy73.aspx) overwrite.

If the XML is large, you should consider using [`CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do in this way:

```
          cnn = new SqlConnection();
          cnn.ConnectionString = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
          cnn.Open();

          string selectQry = "SELECT [Xml] FROM [Table1] WHERE [PK_ID] = @ID";
          cmd = new SqlCommand(selectQry, cnn);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);

          XmlReader reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();

          if (reader.Read())
             xdoc.Load(reader);
```